# Jquery-mobile popup zlevel issue on Android 4.0

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

With Jquery mobile 1.4.2 (latest currently) I've encountered a problem with the popup feature on Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

When displayed the popup appears behind the rest of the page content (can be simulated with a `z-index:1` on `ui-popup-container`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this problem was a bit tweaky : add a `-webkit-transform:translateZ(0)`  :

```
.ui-popup-container {
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(0)
}
```

(I had to shared this, I lost to much time on it !)